# How to avoid having to use "std::static_pointer_cast" when calling a friend function of a template base class with a derived instance

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a template base class with a friend function that can make an operation (`connect`) with another class. If I derive a class from such template base I need to make use of `std::static_pointer_cast<base<whatever_type>>` when calling the friend function passing a derived class instance I would like to find a way for the friend function to accept an instance of the derived class without having to perform the `static_pointer_cast`. I guess I need to find a way to declare the friend function such that template argument deduction would work it out?

Code below:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
    
template<class T>
class base;
    
template<class T>
class extractor;
    
template<class T>
auto connect(std::shared_ptr<base<T>> node,
             std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>> ext);    
    
// A queue adaptator that allows only to pop elements
template<class ValueType>
class extractor
{
public:
    friend auto connect<ValueType>(std::shared_ptr<base<ValueType>>,
                                   std::shared_ptr<extractor<ValueType>>);

    void pop()
    {
        queue->pop();
    }
      
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::queue<ValueType>> queue;
};
    
    
// A collection of replicated queues that allows only to push elements
template<class T = void*>
class base
{
public:
    
    friend auto connect<T>(std::shared_ptr<base<T>>,
                           std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>>);
    
    void push(const T& e)
    {
        for (auto & o : output)
        {
            o.second->push(e);
        }
    }
    
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>>,
                     std::shared_ptr<std::queue<T>>> output;
};
    
template<class T>
auto connect(std::shared_ptr<base<T>> node,
             std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>> ext)
{
    if (ext == nullptr)
    {
        ext.reset(new extractor<T>);
    }
        
    auto q = std::make_shared<std::queue<T>>();
    node->output.emplace(ext, q);
    ext->queue = q;   
}
    
    
// A user type that puts number 42
class foo : public base<int>
{
public:
    
  void do_something()
  {
      push(42);
  }
    
};
    
// A user type that pops from an input
class bar : public base<>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<extractor<int>> input;
      
    void do_something_else()
    {
        input->pop();
    }
};   
    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto pusher = std::make_shared<foo>();
    auto poper  = std::make_shared<bar>();
    
    // Here is the problem: I do not want client code to have to use "static_pointer_cast"
    connect(std::static_pointer_cast<base<int>>(pusher), poper->input);
    
    // Would like to be able to use:
    connect(pusher, poper->input);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Clang error if I do not do the `static_pointer_cast`:

```
stack_overflow.cpp:107:5: error: no matching function for call to 'connect'
    connect(pusher, poper->input);
    ^~~~~~~
stack_overflow.cpp:58:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'base<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'foo'
auto connect(std::shared_ptr<base<T>> node,
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? The compiler can't deduce the template type otherwise. Also why are you using friend functions instead of (`static`?) class member functions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fact that the compiler will try to deduce the type T from the given argument and it can't resolve `foo` to the argument `base<int>`. Casting to a base type is not considered when trying to match a template argument, in contrast to matching a function from an *overload* set.

In this particular case, because the type T can already be determined from the second function argument, you can tell the compiler not to attempt to match the first argument, for instance by changing the declaration of `connect()` in this way:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
auto connect(std::shared_ptr<base<typename identity<T>::type>> node,
             std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>> ext);
```

Plugging this into your complete example renders the following:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
    
template<class T>
class base;
    
template<class T>
class extractor;

template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
auto connect(std::shared_ptr<base<typename identity<T>::type>> node,
             std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>> ext);    
    
// A queue adaptor that allows only to pop elements
template<class ValueType>
class extractor
{
public:
    friend auto connect<ValueType>(std::shared_ptr<base<typename identity<ValueType>::type>> ,
                                   std::shared_ptr<extractor<ValueType>>);
    
    void pop()
    {
        queue->pop();
    }
      
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::queue<ValueType>> queue;
};
    
    
// A collection of replicated queues that allows only to push elements
template<class T = void*>
class base
{
public:
    
    friend auto connect<T>(std::shared_ptr<base<typename identity<T>::type>>,
                           std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>>);
    
    void push(const T& e)
    {
        for (auto & o : output)
        {
            o.second->push(e);
        }
    }
    
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>>,
                     std::shared_ptr<std::queue<T>>> output;
};


template<class T>
auto connect(std::shared_ptr<base<typename identity<T>::type>> node,
             std::shared_ptr<extractor<T>> ext)
{
    if (ext == nullptr)
    {
        ext.reset(new extractor<T>);
    }
        
    auto q = std::make_shared<std::queue<T>>();
    node->output.emplace(ext, q);
    ext->queue = q;   
}
    
    
// A user type that puts number 42
class foo : public base<int>
{
public:
    
  void do_something()
  {
      push(42);
  }
    
};
    
// A user type that pops from an input
class bar : public base<>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<extractor<int>> input;
      
    void do_something_else()
    {
        input->pop();
    }
};   
    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto pusher = std::make_shared<foo>();
    auto poper  = std::make_shared<bar>();
    
    // Here is the problem: I do not want client code to have to use "static_pointer_cast"
    connect(std::static_pointer_cast<base<int>>(pusher), poper->input);
    
    // Would like to be able to use:
    connect(pusher, poper->input);
        
    return 0;
}
```